# How to create multiple instances of bot object that handles all the dialogs from app

Tags: botframework

/ Create the bot object that provides the turn handler function.
const bot = new SimplePromptBot(conversationState, userState);

[bot.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt/bot.js) has SimplePromptBot class which creates bot object.

I am writing a bot code in nodejs botbuilder v4 sdk. I'm trying to know how can I create more than 1 bot objects.

ex:- If my bot supports 3 features as follows.

meeting booking, hotel booking , flight booking

Do I need to create bot object like follows ?

```
const bot1 = new FlightBookingBot(conversationState, userState);
const bot2 = new HotelBookingBot(conversationState, userState);
const bot3 = new MeetingBookingBot(conversationState, userState);
```

If Yes, how can I handle onTurn() for each of those ?

```
await bot.onTurn(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create three separate bots; however, I would recommend creating one bot that has three waterfall dialogs - one for each feature. Then in the `onTurn` method you can direct your conversation flow to the correct waterfall dialog.

Take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt/bot.js) to get an idea of how to create a bot with multiple waterfall dialogs.

Hope this helps!